# Classification points based on their position

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, classification, pybrain

I would like to train, ask and check my Neural Network with points positions.

I have got a file with INI file structure which contain a list of points sorted by their class.
For example:

```
[points]
c_0 = (0, 0)#(1, 1)#(0,1)
c_1 = (5, 5)#(6, 6)#(10, 10)
```

I had parsed the file and I tried to learn my Neural Network which is from PyBrain library. So I made a code like this

```
net = buildNetwork(2, 3, 1, bias=True)
new_params = np.array([1.0]*13)
net._setParameters(new_params)
ds = SupervisedDataSet(2, 1)

for (class) ... # loop for every class
    for (point) ... # loop for every point in class
        ds.addSample(point, class)

trainer = BackpropTrainer(net, ds)
print(trainer.train())
```

So it is a linear function and I could recognize to which class later points will be assigned.

But then when I use even points from file for class 0, 1 or 2 i still got the same result.

For example:

```
>>> net.activate([0, 0])
4.
>>> net.activate([4, 4])
4.
```

I think I am doing it wrong. Maybe there is a better library for this? I don't need anything more than what I wrote about.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the problem:

> **trainer.train()**
>
> This call trains the net for one full epoch and returns a double proportional to the error. If we want to train the network until convergence, there is another method:
>
> **trainer.trainUntilConvergence()**

```
import numpy as np
from pybrain.tools.shortcuts import buildNetwork
from pybrain.datasets.supervised import SupervisedDataSet
from pybrain.supervised.trainers import BackpropTrainer


c_0 = [(0, 0), (1, 1), (0,1)]
c_1 = [(5, 5), (6, 6), (10, 10)]
c_2 = [(20, 20), (23, 23), (25, 25)]

net = buildNetwork(2, 3, 1, bias=True)
new_params = np.array([1.0]*13)
net._setParameters(new_params)
ds = SupervisedDataSet(2, 1)


for point in c_0:
    ds.addSample(point, 0)
for point in c_1:
    ds.addSample(point, 1)
for point in c_2:
    ds.addSample(point, 2)

trainer = BackpropTrainer(net, ds)
trainer.trainUntilConvergence()


print(net.activate([-1, -1]))  # [-0.09622381] ~0 - classify for cluster 0
print(net.activate([7, 7]))    # [ 0.95804033] ~1 - classify for cluster 1
print(net.activate([26, 26]))  # [ 2.04101203] ~2 - classify for cluster 2
```

Comment: Im actually checking this, but it takes a lot of time for like ten tousends of points and 10 clusters :P

Comment: I added a comment below.